# Is there anyway to rewrite woocommerce-template.php?

Tags: plugins

I am trying to do some customizations on the woocommerce-template.php file but I fear it will be overwrite on the next update.

I wonder if there is a way to rewrite a function from functions.php with another one loading my custom file.

This is the function present within woocommerce:

```
public function include_template_functions() {
    include_once( 'woocommerce-template.php' );
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to overwrite it or anyother way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the functions in that file are [pluggable functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), you can define any of those functions in your theme's `functions.php` file or another plugin and they will override the WooCommerce core functions.

There are also a number of [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) in most of those functions which may allow you to do what you want without having to override the entire function.

Comment: I added the following to functions.php: function custom_woocommerce_content() {
 include_once( 'woocommerce-template.php' );
}
but nothing happend

Comment: you don't want to try to load your own version of the file or override the function that loads the file, you want to override the specific functions *within* the file.

Comment: How can I override function woocommerce_content I'm not much of an expert and I'm not understanding the documentation much :(

Comment: copy the whole function including `if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_content' ) ) {` and paste it into your `functions.php` file, that's it. when the woocommerce core file is loaded, it'll reach the `function_exists` check and won't load the core function because your version already exists.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks I didn't know this was possible.